# ng-click is not working on dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am developing an app with angular and i need to insert some data from a webservice. I create the divs dynamically:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < data.Output.length ; i++){   
          var listitem = document.createElement("div");
           listitem.setAttribute("ng-click","doMove()");
          listitem.className = "list-item";
          var name = document.createElement("span");
          name.className = "name"
          name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.Output[i].name));
          var link = document.createElement("a");
          link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('›'));


          listitem.appendChild(name);
          listitem.appendChild(link);
        wrapper.appendChild(listitem);
        }
```

The problem is that clicking on the div does not trigger that function.

UPDATE The data is from a http request.

UPDATE 2: the divs are put into:

```
     <div id = "wrapper">
--->
     </div>
```

I get the date in the cotroller like this:

```
var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: url",
        data: data,

        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
        });

        request.success(function (data) {

        });
```

Comment: Maybe you should look into `ng-repeat` for creating dynamic content. Else angular wont get to know these attributes and the functions. If thats not enough look into `$compile`, but i would go with ng-repeat

Comment: @Hoyen you don`t have to be rude... if i knew angular i woldn`t have been asking

Comment: thank you @Astasian

Comment: can you please give me some directions on how i can transform it using ng-repeat. i am not figuring it out :). @Astasian

Comment: Yes I'll write it as answer

Comment: thank you :) please note that i am getting the data via http request in the controller

Answer (score 2):

As one comment suggested, you should try to do this declaratively with `ng-repeat`.  However if you're stuck doing this in JS, you should make a directive.  In order to attach angular-ish constructs to newly created DOM content for a directive you need to use the `$compile` service.

For `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.output">
    <div class="list-item" ng-click="doMove()">
        <span>...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For a directive approach, in your link function you'd do the same thing but use the service like so:

```
 function linkFunc($scope, elem, attrs){

     //make sure to inject the $compile service in your directive
     $compile( elem )( $scope )

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with ng-repeat. I assume that you are using `$scope` and not `controller as`:

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data.Output" ng-show="data" ng-click="doMove()">
    <span>{{d.name}}</span>
</div>
```

By using `ng-show="data"` only if `data` is set, the divs will show. So make it by default `false` or `null` or `undefiend`.

Comment: i am getting the data in the controller if that is what you mean

Comment: Do you set the data in your controller like `$scope.data = receivedData` or do you use your controller in you html like `ng-controller="Ctrl as c"`?

Comment: In the cotroller i do an http request.

Comment: It is always a good idea to split business-logic out of the controllers and into a Service.

Answer (score 1):

I've quickly made you a plunkr.
http://plnkr.co/edit/S5Ch8yGS1eNabJ0SWgBx?p=preview

```js
angular.module('plunker', []);

angular.module('plunker')
  .component('list', {
    controller: 'ListController',
    templateUrl: 'list.html'
  })
  .controller('ListController', function() {
    this.listItems = [
      { name: 'item 1', value: 'Description to describe the item.' },
      { name: 'item 2', value: 'Description to describe the item.' },
      { name: 'item 3', value: 'Description to describe the item.' },
      { name: 'item 4', value: 'Description to describe the item.' },
      { name: 'item 5', value: 'Description to describe the item.' }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <!-- When using a Component, the controllers alias is "$ctrl" by default. -->
  <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.listItems">
    <strong>{{ item.name }}</strong>
    {{ item.value }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so if i asign data.Output to a variable, then i can access it in the page by $ctrl.thatVariable ?

Comment: yes, that is correct. 
By the way, you should check out the free video course for Angular by CodeSchool: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js This helped me a lot to start understanding angular.

Comment: request.success(function (data) {   item = data.Output;  }); then i should be able to acces that by $ctrl.item ?

Comment: I've updated my plunkr to use API-data from:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. See http://plnkr.co/edit/S5Ch8yGS1eNabJ0SWgBx?p=preview

Comment: @BogdanConstantin did this help you? Or are you still having difficulties?

Comment: The thing is that i am using an app builder (IMA BuilderRz) and it does not let me change the service part. I will try tomorow to find the files and change it there. But thank you for the help. But the static part worked